# freeze table header using datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables plugin and trying to freeze my table header, and the table is created using displaytag. My issue is that there is some problem with the column width in the header. It is not same as the column width of the body. How to make the header width same as body width?

My code:

```
$("#rates").dataTable({
     "bPaginate": false,
     "sScrollY":  "200px",
     "sScrollX": "100%",
});
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle for this, would really help to diagnose

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma after sScrollX 100% and see.

```
$("#rates").dataTable(
    { 
        "bPaginate": false, 
        "sScrollY": "200px", 
        "sScrollX": "100%"
    }
);
```

Comment: you are using these options only for dataTable?

Comment: table are created by displaytag? you are using dataTables, right.

Comment: yes table is created using displaytag and i am using datatables to fix the header and for sorting